# Is any one know a web framework works fine in all platform?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, blackberry, symbian

Is any one know a framework works fine in all platform?
I'm tired of handling on iOS then go to Android and start handling again then go to WP7 then ....

I need one web framework works in all platform (Mobiles, iPads, Tablets, Laptops)?
Any suggestion will be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, only jQueryMobile have best support on lots of various mobile platforms.

http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Comment: I use jQueryMobile but when finish handling with iOS the Android need a new handling.

Comment: Well I tried a lot of mobile frameworks, Sencha Touch, Kendo Mobile, est.. but only jQueryMobile works ok on WP7 and Simbian, so.. it's sad but it's almost only option at the time..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [PhoneGap/Apache Cordova](http://phonegap.com) - free and open source framework that allows you to create mobile apps using standardized web APIs for the platforms you care about. It is now available for the following platforms: iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone, Palm WebOS, Bada, and Symbian.

You can use it with jQueryMobile, Sencha (just added WP8 support) or other mobile web frameworks.

Comment: I use it but i got a lot of issues about scrolling , fixed header& footer, flickering.

Comment: PhoneGap is "mobile" framework - it's not a WEB framework. also Sencha doesn't work on WP7 and don't work on Symbian phones.. so i would not advise to use Sencha..

Comment: Agree. Sencha does not support Symbian. The jQueryMobile is the best choice for the UI+standardized api (+ some api sugars we all like). But PhoneGap could be very helpful for native functionality access and packaging (the author seems to talk about native apps).

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 works just fine. I have used it extensively.

Comment: [HTML5](http://mobilehtml5.org/) : you can look at this link, there are some messing platform.

Answer (score 0):

Infragistics Ignite UI framework is cross platform (mobile, desktop, tablets, etc). Take a look: [Ignite UI](http://www.infragistics.com/products/jquery/)